# Android: Handling GPS from multiple activities

Tags: android, gps

I'm working on an Android app that uses the GPS from multiple activities.
I was looking for a good way to access the GPS from all activities without start/stopping the GPS (receiving events) each time I move from one activity to the other.
In this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5783611/android-best-way-to-implement-locationlistener-across-multiple-activities) it is recommended to use a service and bind/unbind on OnStart/OnStop since they overlap.

I really like the idea however, I've left with one problem.
I'd the like to stop the GPS when my app is no longer active (i.e, home button was pressed).
In this case, only the OnPause will be called.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I've used this approach, it works fine if you unbind in onStop(). That method will be called when your application is no longer visible. Pressing the home key will make your application invisible.

Log when I go from select activity to OSM activity, to Google map activity, then hit home button. (OSM and Google both use the service with the GPS location listener) (I paused the OSM activity to change a preference setting, hence the pause and restart)

```
04-15 17:41:47.903: D/ACTIVITY(376): Select Mode Activity onPause
04-15 17:41:47.953: D/ACTIVITY(376): OSM Activity onCreate
04-15 17:41:48.043: D/ACTIVITY(376): OSM Activity onStart
04-15 17:41:48.063: D/ACTIVITY(376): OSM Activity onResume
04-15 17:41:49.394: D/ACTIVITY(376): Select Mode Activity onStop
04-15 17:42:04.213: D/ACTIVITY(376): OSM Activity onPause
04-15 17:42:04.763: D/ACTIVITY(376): OSM Activity onStop
04-15 17:43:00.483: D/ACTIVITY(376): OSM Activity onStart
04-15 17:43:00.533: D/ACTIVITY(376): OSM Activity onResume
04-15 17:43:20.683: D/ACTIVITY(376): OSM Activity onPause
04-15 17:43:20.723: D/ACTIVITY(376): Google Activity onCreate
04-15 17:43:20.853: D/ACTIVITY(376): Google Activity onStart
04-15 17:43:20.873: D/ACTIVITY(376): Google Activity onResume
04-15 17:43:21.307: D/ACTIVITY(376): OSM Activity onStop
04-15 17:43:40.833: D/ACTIVITY(376): Google Activity onPause
04-15 17:43:41.403: D/ACTIVITY(376): Google Activity onStop
```

Comment: Are you sure OnStop is called after the app is invisible? because I'm printing out all the states of my activities and I see that only OnResume is called when I press the home button.
The OnStop is called only if I run another app (after pressing the home button).

Comment: Yes, I'm sure, edited my post to include my logging of all the on..() methods in the activities. Does it in the emulator and on my phone

Comment: That's weird. I'm running on my phone and in the emulator (2.3) and OnStop is not called after pressing the home button. Maybe I'll try a different OS version.

Answer (score 0):

When ever we press Home button any other activity come in fore ground a part from activity life cycle method we also have an method that is called onUserLeaveHint method.

onUserLeaveHint() is a protected method as other lifecycle methods of the activity and if you are handling onUserLeaveHint this will take care of the following case

When User hits home key

When User hits back key

When User hits annunciator bar

Basically it hints about the user is trying to leave your activity. That means if you are handling onUserLeaveHint() you don’t need to handle onBackPressed() in your code.

Comment: 10x but I'll get the same event for the back key so it doesn't really solve the problem.

Comment: so you wanna to differentiate between back key and home key

Comment: The problem is not only with the home button, for example, when an incoming call arrives.