# Android GPS not working for me

Tags: android, gps

My app has two activities that need GPS, so I tried to offload it to a separate class that either activity could use. I found an answer here that looked easy enough
[Android - Best way to implement LocationListener across multiple activities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5783611/android-best-way-to-implement-locationlistener-across-multiple-activities)
But of course, it's not working for me. I was wondering if anyone can see the issue. I used pretty much exactly the same code, but I got rid of the gps settings dialog.

Here's my GPS class

```
package fieldlayout.skipmorrow.com.fieldlayout;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.location.LocationListener;

import android.location.Location;
import android.util.Log;


/**
 * Created by skip on 4/20/2015.
 */
public class GPS {
    private IGPSActivity main;

    // Helper for GPS-Position
    private LocationListener mlocListener;
    private LocationManager mlocManager;

    private boolean isRunning;

    public GPS(IGPSActivity main) {
        this.main = main;

        // GPS Position
        mlocManager = (LocationManager) ((Activity) this.main).getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        mlocListener = new MyLocationListener();
        mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mlocListener);
        // GPS Position END
        this.isRunning = true;
        Log.i("FieldLayout_GPS", "GPS Object created");
    }

    public void stopGPS() {
        if(isRunning) {
            mlocManager.removeUpdates(mlocListener);
            this.isRunning = false;
        }
        Log.i("FieldLayout_GPS", "stopGPS");
    }

    public void resumeGPS() {
        mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mlocListener);
        this.isRunning = true;
        Log.i("FieldLayout_GPS", "resumeGPS");
    }

    public boolean isRunning() {
        return this.isRunning;
    }

    public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {

        private final String TAG = MyLocationListener.class.getSimpleName();

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
            GPS.this.main.locationChanged(loc.getLongitude(), loc.getLatitude());
            Log.i("FieldLayout_GPS", "onLocationChanged");
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
            Log.i("FieldLayout_GPS", "onStatusChanged");
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            Log.i("FieldLayout_GPS", "onProviderEnabled");
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            Log.i("FieldLayout_GPS", "onProviderDisabled");
        }
    }

}
```

The interface file

```
package fieldlayout.skipmorrow.com.fieldlayout;

/**
 * Created by skip on 4/20/2015.
 */
public interface IGPSActivity {
    public void locationChanged(double longitude, double latitude);
}
```

And my implementation from my activity

```
package fieldlayout.skipmorrow.com.fieldlayout;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;


public class StartActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements IGPSActivity{

    private Location currentLocation;
    private GPS gps;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_start);
        gps = new GPS(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        if (!gps.isRunning()) gps.resumeGPS();
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        // Disconnecting the client invalidates it.
        Log.i("FieldLayout_StartAct", "onStop called. Disconnecting GPS client");
        gps.stopGPS();
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    public void locationChanged(double longitude, double latitude) {
        Log.i("FieldLayout_StartAct", "locationChanged");
        currentLocation.setLatitude(latitude);
        currentLocation.setLongitude(longitude);
    }
}
```

The only log I am seeing is the creation of the GPS object. None of the other methods in the listener are being executed.

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Sorry about that. I edited the post. Basically, nothing in the listener seems to be executing. I don't get any of those log entries at all.

Comment: Do you have the required permissions, e.g. <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

Comment: Can you post your manifest?

Comment: Sorry, I cannot post the manifest right now, but I can assure you that I do have that in the manifest. Yesterday I moved all of my working gps code out of my startactivity to put it in a separate class. It was working yesterday before I did it this way, so I know it isn't a permission issue. I am work now, and these are the only files I copied over, so I don't have access to the manifest, but if you think it warrants a double check, I can post it in a few hours.

Comment: My suggestion is to run the original code first, and then modify it to be what you want. Did you try to go outdoors? Did you try to use the network as location provider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GPS class constructor contains this row:

```
 public GPS(IGPSActivity main) {
    this.main = main;

    // GPS Position
    mlocManager = (LocationManager) ((Activity) this.main).getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
...
}
```

And your interface looks like this:

```
public interface IGPSActivity {
    public void locationChanged(double longitude, double latitude);
```

}

So, the GPS class get an interface, and you want to cast it into an Activity to get a system service from it. That is not going to work.

Change your GPS class a little bit. For example:

```
public GPS(IGPSActivity main, Activity activity){
    mlocManager = (LocationManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
...
}
```

Call this in your activity:

```
gps = new GPS(this, this);
```

Comment: Looks interesting, and you might be on to something. I won't be able to test it for a few more hours, but I'll let you know if it works when I do.

Comment: Yep, it did work and yes, I did forget you! Sorry :)